# Using a String to reference a label I need to set text of?

Tags: java

So right now I have a loop to assign names to players depending on the amount selected and need to somehow construct a string to reference the labels which look some like "lblplayer1" - "lblplayer6" my code looks like this:

```
for (int i=1; i <= noofplayers; i++)
{
    String hello = "lblplayer" + i;
    hello?.setText("hi");
}
```

The last line needs to some equate to the variable name of lblplayer (1-6) without hard coding in the last number.
Basically I need to somehow automatically be able to set the text of each the labels somehow using the array index but not sure how to do this in any way?

Comment: You can't dynamically name variables in java. Use an `array` or a `Map`.

Answer (score 1):

You should create an array of `Label`s:

```
playerLabels[i].setText("hi");
```

Comment: is it not noofplayers[i] ??

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear but I need to set the text of a label with a variable instance of lblplayeri where i is the index array so it will come out like lblplayer1.setText("hi")

Comment: @user2316413: Yes.  You should create an array instead.

Answer (score 0):

dynamic naming is not the best approach in this case. (though it may be possible through reflection).

I would suggest you to maintain a hashmap. so that you can always lookup the object based on the name.

Or alternatively, if names are based on numbers, (label1, label2 etc..) instead you can use an arraylist, so that you can always lookup the objects based on index.

For example, 1st approach can be use like this:

```
public static HashMap<String, Label> map = new HashMap<>();
public void createPlayer(int playerindex){
    Label label = new Label();
    map.put("player"+index, label);
}

public Label getPlayerLabel(int playerindex){
    return map.get("player"+index)  
}
```

**Ps:** this is not exact code just the dummy representation

Comment: Could you possibly explain how either could be implemented? All names are based on numbers player1, player2 and so on.

Comment: I see, but I don't need to create the Labels they already exist I just need to set their Text

Answer (score 0):

Array of object:

```
ObjectPlayer lblplayer[] = new ObjectPlayer[noofplayers];
for (int i=0; i <= noofplayers; i++)
{
    lblplayer[i].setText("hi");
}
```

Comment: What is ObjectPlayer meant to be in this code? It's just giving me an error.

Comment: @user2316413 woops, did you just copy that? I think you should replace that with your class or whatever class you want to use, that has setText method of course.